# How to loop through all sample paths in list of lists: [[1,2,3,],[1,2,3],...]

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-loops, nested-lists

I require the capability to do nested loops over various lists, for example:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [1,2,3]
C = [1,2,3]

for a in A:
   for b in B:
      for c in C:
         #do something
```

What I want to have some code that can take the list of lists given by `[A]+[B]+[C]` and loop over every sample path (i.e. the same thing as the above nested loops is doing).

It is okay if this code takes up 2 or 3 lines, since in my real world example I have not just `A,B,C` but also `D,E,F,G,...` so doing a nested loop as above is way too tedious.

Comment: `A + B + C` will give you another list, not a list of lists.

Comment: @wim Fixed. Also the permutations suggestion won't work I think. I'm looking for nested loop functionality a not permutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the *product* of the three lists; using [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) lets you collapse the three nested loops to:

```
from itertools import product

for a, b, c in product(A, B, C):
```

Because `A == B == C` here, you could simplify that further to:

```
for a, b, c in product(A, repeat=3):
```

If you have multiple lists to produce a product of, put them in a list so you can produce the product of a variable number of input lists:

```
lists = [A, B, C, D, E]
for combination in product(*lists):
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a cartesian product from itertools:

```
from itertools import product
for x in product(A,B,C):
   print x
```